# How to cancel CellEnter/CellLeave event in C#?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I have `DataGridView`. In some cells I add some data. If the cell, that I'm currently editing, is empty and I'm about to leave it, a message "bla-bla-bla" is shown to the user and the cell in edition mode must receive the focus back.

For doing this I'm using `CellEnter`, `CellLeave`, `CellEndEdit` etc. and I want cancel those events after checking the value entered in the cell. But Im noob and it doesn't work. Please, help me. Would be glad to see any advice.

Here is a variant of my code. I tried with other events, but it is very **naive**.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty cell!");

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code so help would be based on it.

Comment: @cppanda >does this need to be solved by code? Yes

Comment: So what you want is to not let the user abandon the edition mode is the value entered is not an "acceptable value" for you?

Comment: @Luis Quijada   Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you must look for a solution based on the `CellValidating` event of the `DataGridView`.

It is fired just when the `DataGridView` is about to leave the edition mode and allows you to not accept the value that has been entered by the user. To reject the value entered, in the code of the event-handler, you must set the `e.Cancel` to `True`.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsValueValid(e.FormattedValue))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        MessageBox.Show("Not Valid!");
    }
}
```

There are many examples in the web, one can be found directly in the documentation of `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs.aspx). *Take a look also to the documentation of the property [DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs.FormattedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs.formattedvalue.aspx)*

Note that the method `IsValueValid(Object o)` is not part of the `DataGridView` component, is just a naming example, you should declare it in your code and provide a body for the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** disable the DataGrids CellEnter CellLeave Events for certain cells or rows.

What you could do is Store a List<> of Cells which are empty / where the enter/leave event should not be called, and before doing stuff in CellEnter / CellLeave check if the Cell is in the list of disabled cells.

Comment: I'll think about it. Thank you.